# How to count an argument with a space and an input as one argument in C?

Tags: c, arguments, argv, argc

I enter the following command line:

```
./file -a 1 -b2 -a5 -b 55 -b4
```

The output I get is:

```
a: 1
argv[1]: -a
b: 2
argv[2]: 1
a: 5
argv[3]: -b2
b: 55
argv[4]: -a5
b: 4
argv[5]: -b
Counter: 5
```

The output I wish to get should be:

```
a: 1
argv[1]: -a 1
b: 2
argv[2]: -b2
a: 5
argv[3]: -a5
b: 55
argv[4]: -b 55
b: 4
argv[5]: -b4
Counter: 5
```

Arguments with a space are currently counted as 2 arguments. I would like my program to count it as 1 argument only (I want it sees "-a 1". Not "-a" and "1" separately).

This is the source code I use I get the outputs:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <getopt.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int opt = 0;
    int quantum1 = 0, quantum2 = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv,"a:b:")) != -1) 
    {
        switch (opt) 
        {                           
             case 'a' : 
                quantum1 = atoi(optarg); 
                printf("a: %d\n", quantum1);
                break;

             case 'b' : 
                quantum2 = atoi(optarg);
                printf("b: %d\n", quantum2);
                break;

             default: 
                printf("Error\n");
                return 1;
                break;
        }
        counter++;
        printf("argv[%d]: %s\n", counter, argv[counter]);
    }

    printf("Counter: %d\n", counter);

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** The quotation marks suggested work, but I'm not allowed to use quotation marks or any other symbols.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
./file "-a 1" -b2 -a5 "-b 55" -b4
```

to make "-a 1" as the first argument and "-b 55" as the fourth argument.

If you are now allowed to use quotation marks, you can escape the space in linux using:

```
./file -a\ 1 -b2 -a5 -b\ 55 -b4
```

Comment: I'm not allowed to use the backslash neither or any other symbols. It has to be the option (-a) and an input(1) only.

Comment: If you are not allowed to use a single quote, a double quote, or an escape character, I don't think there is anyway you can make your program get `-a 1` as a single argument.

Comment: It already does get `-a 1` as a single argument.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not in the way the arguments are being parsed.  The problem is the way the code displays the arguments.  Specifically, when a space exists between the option and the argument, the `optind` will advance by two.  `optind` is an external variable that `getopt` uses to keep track of the next index into the `argv` array.

So if you simply eliminate the `counter` and the lines shown below, you'll find that your code is already working correctly.

```
    counter++;
    printf("argv[%d]: %s\n", counter, argv[counter]);

printf("Counter: %d\n", counter);
```

---

If you absolutely must have a count of the number of arguments found, then simply update the `counter` in each `case` statement, e.g.

```
        case 'a' :
            counter++;
            ...

        case 'b' :
            counter++;
            ...
```

and then print the counter at the end.  It's the `printf("argv[%d]: %s\n", counter, argv[counter]);` line that's getting you confused.  That line serves no useful purpose and should be removed.

---

For a command line of `./test -a1 -b 2`, the strings in argv will be

```
argv[0]: "./test"
argv[1]: "-a1"
argv[2]: "-b"
argv[3]: "2"
```

When you call `getopt` the first time, it will read `argv[1]` and will recognize the `-a` as one of the options that you've specified, so it splits the string into two parts and returns the `'a'` while setting the `optarg` to `"1"`.

When you call `getopt` the second time, it will read `argv[2]` and will recognize the `-b` option.  Since you've specified that `-b` takes an argument, but `argv[2]` doesn't contain the argument, `getopt` will take `argv[3]` as the argument.  Hence it returns the `'b'` while setting the `optarg` to `"2"`.

The bottom line is that `getopt` is designed to ignore the white space between the option and its argument. It does that by processing two of the `argv` strings if the user put white space between the option and its argument.

Comment: I see. The counter counts "-a 1" and "-a1" as 1 argument, but the argv[counter] doesn't display "-a 1" and "-a1" as one.

Comment: When I enter the cmd: ./test -a1 -b 2
The counter counts correctly the argc (there are 3 argc).
When I try to display the argv[counter-1] (argv starts with case 0), it doesn't display "-b 2", but "-b" instead.

Comment: @LordRixuel I've updated the answer to explain how getopt processes the strings in the argv array.

Comment: So is it not possible to include the white space between the option and its argument?